# Date toStartofWeek() On Sunday?

Tags: apex, datetime, date

Here is my code:

```
Date myDate = startTime.Date();       //e.g. myDate =2016-03-01  
Date weekStartDate = myDate.toStartofWeek(); //weekStartDate results 2016-28-02
```

When `myDate` equals `2016-03-01` the value of `weekStartDate` is `2016-28-02`. According to my understanding it should be `2016-29-02`.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in the US, the week starts on Sunday, not Monday. See [Date Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm):

> **toStartOfWeek()**
> Returns the start of the week for the Date that called the method, depending on the context user's locale.
>
> **Signature**
> public Date toStartOfWeek()
>
> **Return Value**
> Type: Date
>
> **Example**
> For example, **the start of a week is Sunday in the United States locale**, and Monday in European locales. For example:

Comment: In other words, if one is getting the wrong value, they should also check their Locale settings.